# How can I pass the result set of filenames from an MySQL query to zip in Linux

Tags: bash, mysql, centos-7

My problem is pretty straight foward, and I think I'm close but need a boost in the right direction.

I have a MySQL table that contains a lot of file names that are used by a website. These files all exist in a directory `images`. What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to `SELECT` some of those file names based on various conditions, and then have those files, and only those files added to a .zip file.

I realized right away that I was having problems with file names that had spaces in them. So I modified my SQL query such that the filenames would be quoted. So what I've ended up with was:

```
zip sample-images $(mysql -u username -pPassword -e "SELECT CONCAT('"', ifnull(products_image, ''), '"'), CONCAT('"', ifnull(products_image_2, ''), '"').... WHERE condition=true" db_name --silent --raw)
```

This outputs a list of all the filenames I'm looking for in the database (along with empty "" entries for the null values), however the result for every line is `zip warning: name not matched: "filename.jpg"`.

Can anybody help me out with this?

**UPDATE**
I believe the issue is something with file name escaping. I've escaped the double-quotes in the query such that the CONCAT's have become `CONCAT('\"', ifnull(products_image, ''), '\"'),....` but still have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
mysql -u username -pPassword -e "SELECT CONCAT('\"', products_image, '\"'), CONCAT('\"', products_image_2, '\"') WHERE condition=true AND products_image IS NOT NULL && products_image_2 IS NOT NULL" db_name --silent --raw --skip-column-names | zip myzipfile.zip -@
```

Although I can't test it right now.

Comment: Same thing, though the output is all on one line per-row returned. Though I do prefer the piped style you suggest better than the sub-shell method I was using.

Answer (score 0):

I would take out the quotes you've added to the SQL and do something like this:

```
mysql -u username -pPassword -e \
"SELECT products_image,products_image_2
WHERE condition=true
AND products_image IS NOT NULL && products_image_2 IS NOT NULL" \
db_name --silent --raw --skip-column-names |
while read FileName
do
zip sample-images "$FileName"
done
```

I've split the line and put in `\` to make it easier to read, but you can join it back together if you wish.  Also, if you prefer you can put the shell code on one line:

```
mysql ... | while read FileName; do zip sample-images "$FileName"; done
```

It's just not as easy to read.

Comment: I will need the quotes for filenames with spaces in them though, no?

Comment: Yes you will need quotes, hence the quotes in `zip images "$FileName"`.